# ASP.NET - Import only 2 excel columns and ignore the other ones

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

can you help me? I have this code to import the first two columns form an excel file and save them into the data table.

```
 connExcel.Open();
 cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "A:B]";
 oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
 oda.Fill(dt);
 connExcel.Close();
```

And what I need now is, that I want to ignore the other columns. For example: Now when I have only first 2 rows filled for columns A and B, only 2 rows should be imported to data table. But the problem is that when there is something in any other column on 10th row, my data table would have also 10 row. The lats 8 of them would be empty, but the still would be there.

How could I do to ignore the other columns?

Comment: maybe change `SELECT *` to `SELECT [column A],[column b]`, etc....* selects all columns.....

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this is not working at all. I could use this instead: `cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT F1, F2 From [" + SheetName + "]";` But it has the same effect as what I used before. The empty rows are imported too.

Comment: ah ok sorry I see what you mean now. Maybe filter WHERE F1<>"" AND F2<>"" to ignore all "empty" rows?

Comment: That could be working, but it's not actually what I want. Because when I would have a table, where one row is missing, this wouldn't be working properly(the row numbering would be wrong).